# Tryton on Windows XP, installation and tutorials?

Tags: python, erp, tryton

I'm trying to use Tryton on Windows XP, but am having a hard time on the installation. I keep having an error like:

> Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

I'm using `easy_install` btw.

Also, can anyone give me a head-start guide on how to use Tryton?

I'm currently having an inventory program. My teacher told me to start using Tryton, but it seems I'm going nowhere in my research :(

Comment: possible solution is at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat or you can use `cygwin` to build your package then transfer that build to your python path

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.exe` directly. You can find this from [Tryton download page](http://downloads.tryton.org/2.6/).